# Using reinterpret cast to save a struct or class to file

Tags: c++, file, serialization, file-io

This is something the professor showed us in his scripts. I have not used this method in any code I have written.

Basically, we take a class, or struct, and reinterpret_cast it and save off the entire struct like so:

```
struct Account
{
    Account()
    {   }
    Account(std::string one, std::string two)
        : login_(one), pass_(two)
    {   }

private:
    std::string login_;
    std::string pass_;
};

int main()
{
    Account *acc = new Account("Christian", "abc123");

    std::ofstream out("File.txt", std::ios::binary);
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(acc), sizeof(Account));
    out.close();
```

This produces the output (in the file)

```
ÍÍÍÍChristian ÍÍÍÍÍÍ              ÍÍÍÍabc123 ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ
```

I'm confused. Does this method actually work, or does it cause UB because magical things happen within classes and structs that are at the whims of individual compilers?

Comment: Yikes. This seems to depend on the internal representation of, for example, `std::string`. Plus it does not take into account `struct` padding and other things that compilers can do.

Comment: In fact, if the implementation of `std::string` dynamically allocates the buffer, this won’t even work. It looks like your standard library caches short strings in the `std::string` object itself, but I bet it would fail for longer strings.

Comment: You can save "something" using this method but don't expect any non-POD fields to survive when you read it back the same way.

Comment: @Nate: Not all version of std::string dynamically allocate the buffer. If the string is small enough (some implementations) hold the buffer inside the string object (this is an implementation detail). As a string object is three or four pointers (if the string is less than the size of all the pointers (32 bytes (probably less)) it can be worth holding it inside the string object instead of in a buffer. Obviously this trick is **non portable** as it depends on the implementation of std::string

Comment: It's not **undefined** behaviour, but it depends on the implementation, and is useless even if you know everything about the implementation.

Comment: @Karl - where, as it stands it isn't, because they aren't reading it back in and trying to use it.  If they did then it would be implementation defined whether or not it caused undefined behavior.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't actually work, but it also does not cause undefined behavior.

In C++ it is legal to reinterpret any object as an array of `char`, so there is no undefined behavior here.

The results, however, are usually only usable if the class is POD (effectively, if the class is a simple C-style struct) and self-contained (that is, the struct doesn't have pointer data members).

Here, `Account` is not POD because it has `std::string` members.  The internals of `std::string` are implementation-defined, but it is not POD and it usually has pointers that refer to some heap-allocated block where the actual string is stored (in your specific example, the implementation is using a small-string optimization where the value of the string is stored in the `std::string` object itself).

There are a few issues:

- You aren't always going to get the results you expect.  If you had a longer string, the `std::string` would use a buffer allocated on the heap to store the string and so you will end up just serializing the pointer, not the pointed-to string.
- You can't actually use the data you've serialized here.  You can't just reinterpret the data as an `Account` and expect it to work, because the `std::string` constructors would not get called.

In short, you cannot use this approach for serializing complex data structures.

Comment: "it also does not cause undefined behavior" - although as you hint at the end, any attempt at deserialization would.

Comment: "usable if the class is POD" omits the importance of ensuring proper alignment on reload...

Comment: @Tony:  Well, the correct approach for reload would be to copy the bytes from the loaded `char` array into an actual object of type `Account`; then you are guaranteed correct alignment.

Comment: yes, if beginners stick to that, it's nice and safe.  Another small point for readers - covered by the slightly over-restrictive "POD" guideline you provide but interesting to contemplate specifically - is that on some architectures this binary read/write approach won't work for objects with pointers to virtual dispatch tables when saving and loading from different processes (whether concurrent processes or after a restart), as the correct VDT address may differ.

Answer (score 4):

This could work depending on the contents of the struct, and the platform on which the data is read back.  This is a risky, non-portable hack which your teacher should not be propagating.

Do you have pointers or `int`s in the struct?  Pointers will be invalid in the new process when read back, and `int` format is not the same on all machines (to name but two show-stopping problems with this approach).  Anything that's pointed to as part of an object graph will not be handled.  Structure packing could be different on the target machine (32-bit vs 64-bit) or even due to compiler options changing on the same hardware, making `sizeof(Account)` unreliable as a read back data size.

For a better solution, look at a **serialization library** which handles those issues for you.  [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) is a good example.

> Here, we use the term "serialization"
>   to mean the reversible deconstruction
>   of an arbitrary set of C++ data
>   structures to a sequence of bytes.
>   Such a system can be used to
>   reconstitute an equivalent structure
>   in another program context. Depending
>   on the context, this might used
>   implement object persistence, remote
>   parameter passing or other facility.

[Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/cpptutorial.html) also works well for simple object hierarchies.

Comment: +1 for the mention of pointers, and the excellent definition of serialization.

Comment: @Thanatos - the definition is a quote from Boost docs fyi.  Does not sound like the professor would have mentioned this though.

Comment: It could not work for any struct that claims to be an implementation of `std::string`, because that must be able to handle an arbitrary (well, almost) length string, and hence use dynamic allocation, and hence a pointer. The example struct contains std::string instances and consequently won't work - the principle applies recursively. Agreed the definition is great, although I would say "transformation" rather than "deconstruction".

Comment: @Karl - this will work and fail apparently unpredictably if the `string` is sometimes heap-based and sometimes direct, as noted in @James's answer.  That makes this example/approach even more misleading.

Answer (score 4):

It's not undefined. Rather, it's platform dependent or implementation defined behavior. This is, in general bad code, because differing versions of the same compiler, or even different switches on the same compiler, can break your save file format.

Answer (score 1):

It's no substitute for proper serialization. Consider the case of any complex type that contains pointers - if you save the pointers to a file, when you load them up later, they're not going to point to anything meaningful.

Additionally, it's likely to break if the code changes, or even if it's recompiled with different compiler options.

So it's really only useful for short-term storage of simple types - and in doing so, it takes up way more space than necessary for that task.

Answer (score 1):

This method, if it works at all, is far from robust. It is much better to decide on some "serialized" form, whether it is binary, text, XML, etc., and write that out.

The key here: You need a function/code to reliably convert your class or struct to/from a series of bytes. `reinterpret_cast` does not do this, as the exact bytes in memory used to represent the class or struct can change for things like padding, order of members, etc.

Answer (score 1):

No.

In order for it to work, the structure must be a POD (plain old data: only simple data members and POD data members, no virtual functions... probably some other restrictions which I can't remember).

So if you wanted to do that, you'd need a struct like this:

```
struct Account {
    char login[20];
    char password[20];
};
```

Note that std::string's not a POD, so you'd need plain arrays.

Still, not a good approach for you. Keyword: "serialization" :).

Comment: The structure does not necessarily have to end with a null terminator: this is only needed if you decide to call C-string functions on the result, which would be incorrect (that `int` probably has a 0 byte, so do those strings...)

Comment: A null terminator isn't required when you can specify the number of bytes to write.

Comment: @Thanatos, yes, I've noted that seconds after posting and edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Some version of string don;t actually use dynamic memory for the string when the string is small. Thus store the string internally in the string object.

Think of this:

```
 struct SimpleString
 {
     char*    begin;        // beginning of string
     char*    end;          // end of string
     char*    allocEnd;     // end of allocated buffer end <= allocEnd
     int*     shareCount;   // String are usually copy on write
                            // as a result you need to track the number of people
                            // using this buffer
 };
```

Now on a 64 bit system. Each pointer is 8 bytes. Thus a string of less than 32 bytes could fit into the same structure without allocating a buffer.

```
 struct CompressedString
 {
     char buffer[sizeof(SimpleString)];
 };
 stuct OptString
 {
     int      type;        // Normal /Compressed
     union
     {
         SimpleString     simple;
         CompressedString compressed;
     }
 };
```

So this is what I believe is happening above.
A very efficient string implementation is being used thus allowing you to dump the object to file without worrying about pointers (as the std::string are not using pointers).

Obviously this is not portable as it depends on the implementation details of std::string.

So interesting trick, but not portable (and liable to break easily without some compile time checks).

Comment: ... and even then, useless if you can't guarantee the string will be "short".