# Problem in reading data of object from file in c++

Tags: c++, file-handling

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class student{

private:
    string name;
    long  int rollNo;
public:
     static int noOfStudent;

    void getData(){
     cout<<"Enter name:";
     getline(cin,name);
     cout<<"Enter Roll No:";
     cin>>rollNo;
    }
    void storeInFile(){

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("studentDataBase.txt",ios::app|ios::binary);
    if(myfile.fail())
        exit(-1);
    myfile.write((char*)this,sizeof(*this));
    myfile.close();
    }
    void  printData(){

    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("studentDataBase.txt",ios::binary);
    if(myfile.fail())
        exit(-1);
    myfile.read((char *)this,sizeof(*this));
    while(!myfile.eof()){
    cout<<this->name<<" "<<this->rollNo<<"\n";
    myfile.read((char *)this,sizeof(*this));
    }
  myfile.close();
    }
};
int student::noOfStudent;
int main()
{
   student st[100];
   st[0].getData();
   st[0].storeInFile();
   st[0].printData();
}
```

This is code for storing name and roll no of student in file and reading from file to print details of students.
But there is problem occuring during reading data from file and printing it.When i run this program,
and enter details of student and then call printData() function,then this program works perfectly.
But when i run this program again and trying to call printData() function only,then in output,some garbage values are shown.I donot able to understand why this is happening??
(very very sorry for long code)

Comment: You can't read a `std::string` this way at all. `myfile.read((char *)this,sizeof(*this));` is definitely a bug. A `std::string` is not a POD type and it has internal pointers that will not be valid when restored. Note that sizeof() is a compile time constant.

Comment: The problem is that the `myfile.write` is writing the `std::string` object, not the text.  So you get all the variables and overhead inside `std::string` object written to the file.  Also, if `std::string` contains a pointer, pointers don't convert back very well because the OS can move your program and its memory allocation on every run of your program.

Comment: Since the text is a *variable length* field, you're going to have to either write the length, then the text or write the text followed by a termination character, like `nul`, `'\0'`.

Comment: I recommend writing out in text format, first the roll number, a space, the student's name, then a newline.  For this small project, you don't need to write in binary; text will do (the file is not huge, so the savings is not worthwhile).

Comment: In this program,I  store object  directly in file,because i also want to make a function which will search student by their rollno.I thought by storing objects,it is easy to search..

Comment: @AmitNandal But you can't store objects in C++, not in the general case anyway. There are **some** objects you can store (so called POD types), but yours isn't one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend writing your data in Whitespace Separated text:

```
myFile << rollNo << " " << name << "\n";
```

This will allow you to read it back like this:

```
myFile >> rollNo;
std::getline(myFile, name);
```

The `std::getline` is used to help synchronize with one record per line and to allow spaces in the student's name.

**Edit 1: Binary Writing**
If you must write in binary mode, I recommend writing the length of the text followed by the text:

```
myFile.write((char *) &rollno, sizeof(rollno));
unsigned int length = name.length();
myFile.write((char *) &length, sizeof(length));
myFile.write(name.c_str(), length);
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas for answering,but  i also want to make a function which will search student by their rollno. I thought searching is difficult by this approach.Correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: You don't want to search a file.  Read objects into memory, then search memory.  See `std::vector` and `std::map`.

Comment: I have one more doubt::> let say i run this program and read objects into memory and then search memory.This works perfectly.But when i close this program and again run this,i can't get access to those objects which i previously created.Then i have to search whole file.any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: There may be a workaround, but is more complicated for your needs.  For your simple program, read the data from the file into memory, as needed by your program.  The objects in the containers will disappear when your program exits;  this is one reason files were invented: storing data after programs exit or power is cycled off.

Comment: To satisfy your curiosity, you'll need to ask the Operating System for a "permanent" area of memory (an area of memory that stays after your program exits).  Use this area of memory; you may want to use an allocator to supply to `std::vector` or `std::map`.  So you'll need to search your OS for the API.  Not all Operating Systems support this feature.  Much simpler to read in the file at the beginning of your program.

Answer (score 3):

I don't recommend doing this thing:

```
myfile.write((char*)this,sizeof(*this));
```

because your `student` class is not [POD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392597/using-reinterpret-cast-to-save-a-struct-or-class-to-file) is explained why with POD it might work.

You are writing the (in your case stack allocated) memory from your program memory space to a file. To read it back later on is undefined behavior. If you would like to save your `student` class to file (i.e. serialize your `student` class), write the corresponding data, like "name" and "rollNo", for example like this: `myfile << name;` in ASCII mode, or `myfile.write(name.c_str(), name.size());` in binary mode. Or even better, use some good serialization tools. I can recommend [boost serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

Comment: *Never do that thing:* That's too strong. There are cases where one can use `ofstream::write` and `ifstream::read` without any problem and there are cases where one cannot use them. An exaplanation of that would add great value to your answer.

Comment: You are right, I explained a bit.